# Encrypt/decrypt android database for quiz application

Tags: android

I am creating a quiz app (paid application).
The app has a database which has got around 3000 questions.
I wanted to know how I can protect the database.
I wanted to know the best and the easy method.

Comment: Protect from what? All the answers seem to completely miss the fact that your database cannot be accessed by any other app.

Comment: And aside from that: You  cannot prevent anyone from reverse engineering your app and just reading that data. The only way to keep your data really safe is to move them to a server and access them through a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **sqlcipher**,refer to [this link](http://sqlcipher.net/).
now I am using it ,it's very good one(it's free for android but not for Ios)

Answer (score 0):

An easy method would be to simply use the ProGuard which is built-in to android. It will make your data harder to find. All you have to do is enable ProGuard in your `build.gradle` file (for AS).

Since it's not critical data, in my opinion this level of security would be more than enough.

[ProGuard in the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)